# How to test material ui autocomplete google map with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm trying to make a test for the material ui autocomplete component, I'm using the same component in this [example](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#google-maps-place), I tried following the problem from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882089/how-to-test-material-ui-autocomplete-with-react-testing-library) but I didn't find how to solve it.

the code of my test is the following, the problem is that I get only the city I type in the input and not the first result. I test it a little and I think it doesn't select the available options with the `ArrowDown` and `Enter`.

```
// Autocomplete is the Autocomplete component from material ui
      test("Autocomplete Test", async () => {
        render(<Autocomplete />);
        const autocomplete = screen.getByTestId("autocomplete");
    
        const input = within(autocomplete).getByRole("textbox");
    
        autocomplete.click();
        autocomplete.focus();
    
        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "london" } });
        fireEvent.keyDown(autocomplete, { key: "ArrowDown" });
        fireEvent.keyDown(autocomplete, { key: "Enter" });
    
      const inputt = within(autocomplete).getByRole("textbox");
    
      console.log(inputt.value);
    
      expect(inputt.value).toEqual("London");
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i take the first component from your link to [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#combo-box), the test below will actually succeed.

Component:

```
      <Autocomplete
        data-testid="autocomplete"
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
      />
```

and test:

```
describe("Foo", () => {
    it("can select the second item and proceed", async () => {

        const { debug, getAllByRole } = render(<Foo />);
        const autocomplete = screen.getByTestId("autocomplete");

        const input = within(autocomplete).getByRole("textbox");

        autocomplete.click();
        autocomplete.focus();

        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "lo" } });

        // to be sure, or do `findAllByRole` which is also async
        await act(async () => {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
        });

        fireEvent.click(getAllByRole("option")[1]);

        expect(input.value).toEqual("The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring");
    })

});
```

This will create a successful test. With multi-select it will actually create other html so hence my advise about debugging below.

*Also notice i take debug from the render, so at any point i can see what the html is (calling debug()). This can give you very good pointers in what is painted on the moment you are trying to achieve something! Personally i run tests in watch mode and can set breakpoints from the editor which helps me much more.*

Edit: when i try and rename `fireEvent.click(getAllByRole("option")[1]);` into part below it works as well:

```
   fireEvent.keyDown(input, { key: "ArrowDown" });
   fireEvent.keyDown(input, { key: "Enter" });
```

Comment: I get the following error: TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "option"

Comment: I now gave other example in the edit as well. If still doesnt work, test with next tick by calling:
`
        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "lo" } });

        await act(async () => {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
        });

        fireEvent.click(getAllByRole("option")[1]);
`

Comment: it doesn't work, it doesn't select the elements from the dropdown menu

Comment: i think the autocomplete from the example i linked it's slightly different

Comment: Ah now i looked, in your question it was about material-ui. But your usecase is using the google script on the window. You have to stub google completely

Comment: what do you mean?